# How can you edit the form field for django.contrib.auth cosmestically?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration, django-contrib

I am currently doing the django-registration app which uses the standard Django.contrib.auth models to log users in and out. When you render the Log in page, it shows the field label and field as such:

```
Username: [username field]
Password: [password]

Log in [button]
```

Stylistically I would like to remove the label and put 'username' and password in as a placeholder. It would look like

```
[Enter Username]
[Enter Password]

Log in [button]
```

Is there a way to domestically do this without rewrite the django.contrib.auth log-in process?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to rewrite the login form. Let's assume your urlconf is like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'},
    name='login'),
```

]

Now create login form according to your need in `project/templates/login.html`
put login.html according to your TEMPLATES settings in settings.py

Check example in [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) or [here](http://django-marcador.keimlink.de/en/frontend_login.html) and [here](http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html)